# Lost acces to my databases by revoking permissions - phpMyAdmin MySQL

Tags: mysql, privileges

I accidently revoked every privileges to all of my users (including the default "root" one) on MySQL using phpMyAdmin and I am struggling to find how I could solve my mistake. I can't figure how to acces again to my databases, which don't appear in phpMyAdmin anymore.

I'm struggling so hard trying to find some help to get acces to my DBs again so I hope I will by posting this. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You'll almost certainly have to use terminal tools, not phpMyAdmin.

Comment: [reset root password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: Such things usually happen if "Hardcore-Admins" perform operations directly on the mysql.user table. In this case the best solution would be to restore users from last backup.